# Calling One Laravel API Routes On Another Laravel Project

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-api

I've two **LARAVEL** projects one contains **API** routes and second contains the **views**

**API** end point is running on port **8000** using **command** `php artisan serve`
second one is running on port **8001** using **command** `php artisan serve --port 8001`

I want to display the **JSON** from **API end point** to the **view**
what are the possible ways to do this

I want to perform test my **JSON** data for **view** that's why doing this

Currently doing this

```
        $response = $client->request('GET',
            'http://localhost:8000/api/generate/token', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept'        => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]
        );
        return json_encode($response);
```

but this returns error **Client error 404 Not Found**

Comment: Check your API `artisan route:list`. Is `api/generate/token` exists?

Comment: Did you tried : YOUR_LOCAL_IP/project_name/public/api/... ?

Comment: Do both of your apps have the same APP_KEY?

Comment: yes I've tried locally like localhost:8000/url but it client returning 404
@FouedMOUSSI

Comment: @Artas no app_key is different

Comment: use I've checked route exists 
@WahyuKristianto

Comment: @ZohaibFaruqui is the api returning the 404 error or is the calling app returning it?

Comment: the guzzle client returning 404 @Artas

Comment: facing same kind of issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and this is how I solved it.

1, Run this command

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0

2, Implement your logic like this.

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

```
        $response = $client->request('POST',
        'your endpoint', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]
    );
    return json_encode($response);
```

For more details check this website

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run `php artisan cache:clear` and then run `php artisan serve --port=<your_prefered_port>`